# How to start a Powerpoint 2010 Slideshow using VSTO Addin

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

Is it possible to start a slideshow from a Powerpoint 2010 add-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run`